# Изменть стиль, размер и тип шрифта в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть три чекбокса, QFontComboBox и QSpinBox, а также главное текстовое поле QTextEdit.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы SpinBox изменял размер шрифта, чекбоксы делали текст курсивным, подчеркнутым и полужирным соответственно.

Чекбоксы пробую сделать так:

```
// чекбоксы
if (ItalyStyle->isChecked()) {
   MainTextEdit->setFontItalic(true);
}
if (BoldStyle->isChecked()) {
   MainTextEdit->setFontWeight(true);
}
if (UnderLineStyle->isChecked()) {
   MainTextEdit->setFontUnderline(true);
}
```

Не работает. Если не сложно, помогите.

И еще вопрос - Как установить формат шрифта из QFontComboBox?

Comment: На какой сигнал вы все это вешаете? Продемонстрируйте код

Comment: Обязательно делать отдельный сигнал? Зачем тогда нужна функция isChecked()?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно, можно обойтись и одним для всех чекбоксов. Как у вас это реализовано?

Comment: Вот так реализовано.  connect(ItalyStyle, SIGNAL (isChecked), SLOT(slotCheckBoxactive()));

Comment: isChecked это не сигнал, так работать не будет

Comment: А какой сигнал правильный?

Answer (score 0):

У класса QCheckBox имеется такой сигнал `stateChanged(int state)`.

Если вы хотите один обработчикдля всех чекбоксов, делайте так:

```
class MainClass : ... {
    Q_OBJECT
//...
private slots:
    void checkBoxChanged(int state);
//..
}
```

Реализация:

```
MainClass::MainClass(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    // ...      
    QTextEdit* MainTextEdit = new QTextEdit(this); 
    // ! Обязательно надо задать имя, иначе мы его не найдем
    MainTextEdit->setObjectName("MainTextEdit");

    connect(ItalyStyle, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkBoxChanged(int)));
    connect(BoldStyle, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkBoxChanged(int)));
    connect(UnderLineStyle, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkBoxChanged(int)));
    // ...
}

void MainClass::checkBoxChanged(int state)
{
    // Ищем нужный виджет по его имени
    QTextEdit* MainTextEdit = findChild<QTextEdit*>("MainTextEdit");

    if( MainTextEdit != nullptr )
    {
        // Выбираем нужный чекбокс по имени переменной
        if( sender()->objectName() == "ItalyStyle" )
            MainTextEdit->setFontItalic(state == Qt::Checked);
        else if( sender()->objectName() == "BoldStyle" )
            MainTextEdit->setFontWeight(state == Qt::Checked);
        else if( sender()->objectName() == "UnderLineStyle" )
            MainTextEdit->setFontUnderline(state == Qt::Checked);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Если сделать такую функцию, пишет, что ItalyStyle и другие переменные не объявлены внутри этой функции.

Comment: А MainTextEdit как "объявить"?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH в конструкторе надо добавить строковое имя виджету и далее смотрите слот