# Как сделать текст курсивным в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

В продолжении [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958507/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-qt#958529)

Реализовал полужирный и подчеркнутый таким образом

```
  MainTextEdit->setFontWeight(BoldStyle->isChecked()? QFont::Bold:QFont::Normal);

  MainTextEdit ->setFontUnderline(UnderLineStyle->isChecked()? QFont::UnderlineResolved:QFont::Normal);
```

Курсив реализовать не получается, нет параметра italic. Есть только функция italic ()

```
 MainTextEdit->setFontItalic(ItalyStyle->isChecked() ? QFont::italic:QFont::Normal)
```

Может быть курсив как-то подругому называется? Как сделать текст курсивным похожим образом?

Comment: `setFontItalic` принимает `bool`, следовательно ваше выражение надо записать как `MainTextEdit->setFontItalic(ItalyStyle->isChecked());`

Comment: Проверил, работает. Причем с `underline` такая же история, надо подавать `true/false`, а не элемент `enum`. Правда у меня получилось только если текст, который надо изменить, выделен